# Spanish expression for this specific use of "You want" or "You are looking for..."

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, expresiones

In English, say when correcting someone who has been looking for something in the wrong place, you can use "you want..." to point them into the right direction.

A very contrived example:

> **Person 1:** I'm looking for doctor Miller, I have an appointment with her regarding my heart problem.
>
> **Person 2:** Oh, you want doctor *Moller*. Doctor Miller is an oncologist. She's on the third floor.

Or alternatively:

> **Person 2:** Oh, you're looking for doctor *Moller*. Doctor Miller is an oncologist. She's on the third floor.

Is there a way to express this in Spanish that is as elegant as the English version?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but I think you could say, "Ah, Ud. querrá a la doctora Moller, en el tercer piso."  Technically this is the future tense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "one size fits all" solution for every context. You could use some of these expressions:

- Usted se **refiere** a / Tú te **refieres** a

> Oh, usted se **refiere** al doctor Moller. El doctor Miller es oncólogo. Ella se encuentra en el tercer piso.
>
> Creo que tú te refieres a Mark Walberg. Matt Damon no salía en esa película. Es fácil confundirlos.

- Usted **quiso decir** / Tú **quisiste decir**

> Oh, usted  tal vez **quiso decir** que viene a ver al doctor Moller. El doctor Miller es oncólogo.
>
> Tú **quisiste decir** Canberra verdad? Sidney no es la capital de Australia

- Usted **lo que [realmente] quiere es** / Tú **lo que [realmente] quieres es**

> Oh, usted  **lo que quiere** es ver al doctor Moller. El doctor Miller es oncólogo.
>
> Oh, tú **lo que realmente quieres** son unos altavoces nuevos, no una tarjeta de sonido. Tu ordenador no necesita eso.

This latter one could also be "lo que usted [realmente] **necesita**"

Comment: To an English speaker, *quiso decir* can seem condescending. (The equivalent in English is.) *Lo que quiere* is essentially neutral in tone.

Comment: It's more likely for the third option to be used as "lo que usted [realmente] quiere es/lo que tú [realmente] quieres es". The subject is in the wrong place in your answer.

Comment: I get t about quiso decir sounding condesceding to an English ear.  But the English ear overlooks the fact that quiso decir in Spanish is the way you say "you meant".

Comment: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/querer_decir

Answer (score 0):

> Ah, ¿[Usted] **busca** al doctor Miller?

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Aunque esta respuesta es correcta, te recomiendo ampliar un poco más. Así queda un poco seca. Échale un vistazo a otras respuestas o a la sección [answer]. Bienvenido de nuevo.

Comment: @Diego - Not sure if you were the downvoter.  I think it's enough to give helpful feedback as you did.  I don't see a need to downvote a first time participant for an incomplete answer.

Comment: @aparente001 Don't forget that you have [this template](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2624/5481), if you need a canned message for that suggestion. Also, [see here](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2660/5481). I agree, new users should not be heavily downvoted (which is not the case for this post), but I don't think they should not be downvoted under any circumstances either. A responsible use of the downvote privilege should include **reverting** the vote once the post is fixed. Currently I'm focusing on not having these "new+low quality" contributions deleted upon arrival.

Comment: Para aclarar que "queda un poco seca": primero, las respuestas tan breves suelen terminar en la cola de "low qualitiy" en las [colas de revisión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review) ya que los procesos automáticos del sistema se basan en **longitud** y contenido para marcar contribuciones de baja calidad. Segundo, suele ser buena idea _explicar_ un poco, en lugar de simplemente plantar una solución o respuesta. Viendo que tienes el bonus por asociación, entiendo que no eres del todo ajeno a [answer]. Espero que estos consejos sirvan de ayuda.

Comment: @Diego - Bueno, cada quien tiene su opinión.  Yo pienso que el recien llegado podría desalentarse si recibe un voto negativo en su primera acción en el sitio.  El feedback que diste, creo que sería suficiente para much gente.  Y si no, entonces la segunda vez, ahí sí podría uno empezar a castigar.  Por lo menos así lo veo yo.

Comment: @aparente001, si estamos de acuerdo! No he dado una explicación todo lo verbosa que podía por la limitación de los comentarios, y que esto es una discusión/reflexión para meta. Date cuenta de que si los post aparecen en la cola de "low quality" mucha gente estará tentada a votar "delete". Yo, ni como moderador ni como usuario puedo hacer más, y quizá sea mejor así. No se puede "blindar" a nadie de los votos negativos, que todos recibimos uno tarde o temprano, pero se puede educar a la gente en el uso responsable, a la par que se enseña a los nuevos [ask] y [answer] para crear posts de calidad

Comment: Creo que tienes un hijo pequeño, ¿no?  Me encanta lo que dicen Faber y Mazlish: *Take time to teach*.  A mi aviso los principiantes son como niños tiernos, que no saben todavía cómo comportarse, y que si reciben un castigo, se desalientan.  Pero generalmente están muy abiertos al feedback, si se les da sin humillaciones.  Bueno, eso pienso yo. //  Me parece que tu "Bienvenido pero..." estuvo muy bien.